# Good software to design games and game interfaces?

Tags: graphic-design, game-development, planning

I would like to make the design of my game before implementing it. I would like a tool that let me create scenes with images and arrows to design how my game will look and feel. I'm not really good with paint and I'm looking for something with a bit more snapping. I could use [wireframe.cc](http://wireframe.cc) to plan it like a website however I don't find it really convenient for a plan with multiple scenes. Plus, snapping doesn't work very well with overlapped objects.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Is your game a pixel one?

Comment: @Rafael No, it is not